# What should I fix in the code to make the slider work?

Tags: javascript, slider

There are 2 sliders on the page. In General, the problem is that there is a script that switches the slider by clicking on the arrows, the first `forEach` and by clicking on the text, the second `forEach`.

The first one works without any problems, but the second one skips the first slider and only works with the second one, so switching by text only works with the second slider. Can someone xplain why this is happening and where the error was made?

```
var sliders = document.querySelectorAll('.carousel');

var GodObj = {};

sliders.forEach(function one(items){

  var sl = items.querySelector('.gallery').clientWidth;

  var width = sl;
  var count = 1;

  var list = items.querySelector('ul');
  var listElem = items.querySelectorAll('li');

  var position = 0;

  GodObj.Width = +width;
  GodObj.List = list;

  items.querySelector('.prev').onclick = function(){
  position += width*count;
  position = Math.min(position,0);
  list.style.marginLeft = position + 'px';
  }

  items.querySelector('.next').onclick = function(){
  position -= width*count;
  position = Math.max(position, -width*(listElem.length - count));
  list.style.marginLeft = position + 'px'
  }
});

var textbutton = document.querySelectorAll('.listElementsSlider');

textbutton.forEach(function(items){
  var elClick = items.querySelectorAll('li');
  elClick[0].onclick = function(){
    GodObj.List.style.marginLeft = 0;
  }
  elClick[1].onclick = function(){
    GodObj.List.style.marginLeft = -GodObj.Width*1 + 'px';
  }
  elClick[2].onclick = function(){
    GodObj.List.style.marginLeft = -GodObj.Width*2 + 'px';
  }
  elClick[3].onclick = function(){
    GodObj.List.style.marginLeft = -GodObj.Width*3 + 'px';
  }
  elClick[4].onclick = function(){
    GodObj.List.style.marginLeft = -GodObj.Width*4 + 'px';
  }
});
```

Comment: can you try to put this into a working example and embed it here?

Comment: I can send you files with this project if you give me the address where to send it, it's just not possible to upload it to an online platform right now